# Как отключить рамки вокруг всех элементов в Storyboard?

Tags: xcode, storyboard

Я случайно что-то не то нажал и теперь во всех контроллерах в сториборде каждый элемент обведён рамкой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В меню:

```
Editor -> Canvas -> Show Bounds Rectangles
```

уберите галочку

Comment: Спасибо. Я уже разобрался. Проблема была в том что если я там убирал галочку, то границы не убирались. А когда я переходил на другой файл и возвращался в сториборд, то галочка снова там стояла. В итоге помог перезапуск xcode. Но всё равно спасибо.